# Android: Keep notification text on screen

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

I create a normal foreground service with notification from an activity, then the activity closes itself.

The notification shows up with the icon and text, but after a second or two, it 'switches back' to showing just the icon, along with the other icons that may be there (software update icon, info triangle icon, whatever).

Is there a way to keep the notification text up as well, not just the icon? ...until the service ends.

Comment: Thankfully no, an app should not be blocking other important notifications that might have been presented

Comment: it's a closed kiosk environment, there shouldn't be any other notifications

Comment: Does not matter, unless you run your own ROM you cant do it